# jquery-lightbox strange behavior (won't advance to next/prev image)

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I'm having two behavioral issues that I can't overcome.  First, I can't successfully scroll through images. When I click the Next/Prev buttons within the lightbox, it just stays on the current image.

Additionally, if I click squarely in the middle of the lightbox image, it closes.

```
$(function(){


$('#photos a').lightBox({fixedNavigation:true, imageBtnPrev:'{{site}}media/imageslightbox-btn-prev.gif',imageBtnNext:'{{site}}media/images/lightbox-btn-next.gif',containerResizeSpeed:350,});

});
```

So I've tried this with and without the "fixedNavigation:true" parameter.

My markup is as follows:

```
  <div id="photos">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="{{site}}media/apt-img4.jpg"><img src="{{site}}media/apt-img4.jpg" width="185" height="110" alt="Thumb" /></a></li> 
            <li><a href="{{site}}media/apt-img4.jpg"><img src="{{site}}media/apt-img5.jpg" width="185" height="110" alt="Thumb" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="{{site}}media/apt-img4.jpg"><img src="{{site}}media/apt-img6.jpg" width="185" height="110" alt="Thumb" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="{{site}}media/apt-img4.jpg"><img src="{{site}}media/apt-img7.jpg" width="185" height="110" alt="Thumb" /></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

thanks for any help!

Comment: post your setup in jsfiddle.com. does jquery lightbox require a css file?

Comment: jquery lightbox comes with a css file and it's loading on my page without an issue

Comment: Post the setup on jsfiddle.com it's really easy. Just copy and paste the final page into the html section and then click save and post the url here

Comment: it seems like the app that you're referring to is jsfiddle.net.  I hate to suck like this, but I'm trying to be a bit stealthy right now and I'd rather not post my actual content.  I just went through it and tried to untangle my django templates so that I could post a stripped down version, but it's a pain in the butt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found to problem in your script, but I'm not sure it solve your problem.

1. You have a extra comma in your javascript. It will cause issue in IE. It should be:

   ```
   $('#photos a').lightBox({fixedNavigation:true, imageBtnPrev:'{{site}}media/imageslightbox-btn-prev.gif',imageBtnNext:'{{site}}media/images/lightbox-btn-next.gif',containerResizeSpeed:350});
   ```
2. In your html code, you load the sample image for all the thumbnails. It should be:

   ```
    <div id="photos">
               <ul>
                   <li><a href="{{site}}media/apt-img4.jpg"><img src="{{site}}media/apt-img4.jpg" width="185" height="110" alt="Thumb" /></a></li> 
                   <li><a href="{{site}}media/apt-img5.jpg"><img src="{{site}}media/apt-img5.jpg" width="185" height="110" alt="Thumb" /></a></li>
                   <li><a href="{{site}}media/apt-img6.jpg"><img src="{{site}}media/apt-img6.jpg" width="185" height="110" alt="Thumb" /></a></li>
                   <li><a href="{{site}}media/apt-img7.jpg"><img src="{{site}}media/apt-img7.jpg" width="185" height="110" alt="Thumb" /></a></li>
               </ul>
           </div>
   ```

Comment: thanks YNhat.  my markup was off for some reason and yours is correct.  I'm looking through it and I still can't see it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Brendan - It looks like your original hrefs were all pointing to the same (first) image and YNhat corrected that. If you copied/pasted his markup, that's likely the original reason for the problem.